# SqlDependency doesn't work with LEFT JOIN

Tags: c#, signalr, left-join, sqldependency

I'm trying to use signalr with sqldependency. I tested with :

```
select ACTION_DATE,Id,Type_ID,Customer_ID, Phone, Message, User_ID, 
Status_ID,CREATED_ON,Description from [TLS].[Notification] where user_id='" 
+ Parameters.UserID + "'"
```

and every thing works fine and my event fires when i changed something in db.

But when i tried with Left join then my `On_Change` event doesn't fire:

```
select c.DISPLAY_NAME as CustomerName, n.ACTION_DATE,n.Id,n.Type_ID,
n.Customer_ID, n.Phone,  n.Message, n.User_ID, 
n.Status_ID,n.CREATED_ON,n.Description 
from [TLS].[Notification] AS n Left outer join [TLS].[Customer]  AS c  
on c.ID=n.CUSTOMER_ID 
where user_id='" + Parameters.UserID + "' and n.STATUS_ID<>'3'
```

this is my Method

```
 var messages = new List<SqlDataReader>();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                command.Notification = null;

                var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(SqlNotification.dependency_OnChange);

                return _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>(query);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Looks like [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) likes your queries.

Comment: This is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms181122%28v%3dsql.105%29#supported-select-statements). There's a whole host of restrictions on a query that can be (efficiently) notified on by the engine. Specifically, "the statement must not contain subqueries, outer joins, or self-joins."

Comment: You are right. Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell how you handle this issue please ?